# Google maps v3 markers over infobox

Tags: google-maps-api-3, layer, markers, pane, infobox

I am creating website https://yachtcharterbook.com with google maps v3 in it. I got markers and infowindows which popups on marker mouse over. When infowindows appears i try to navigate over it by mouse but when another marker is under it - current infowindow closes and second one popups. There is problem with layers or panels or z-index i dont realy understand. I tryied playing with infowindow pane: 'floatPane', pane: 'mapPane', zIndex on infowindow and markers but no changes. Maybe you have some ideas why it is happening ?

```
var ib = new InfoBox();
            latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(38.909593, -76.419036);
                marker[282] = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLng,
                map: map,
                icon: defIcon
            });

            var infobox282 = {
                content: document.getElementById('infobox282'),
                disableAutoPan: false,
                maxWidth: 0,
                pane: 'floatPane',
                pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(20, -74),
                zIndex: null,
                alignBottom: false
            };

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker[282], 'mouseover', function() {
                ib.close();
                ib.setOptions(infobox282)
                ib.open(map, this);
            });

<div class="bubble" id="infobox282">
            <h1>США, <span>Chesapeake Bay</span></h1><div class="objects">
                    <div class="link">
                        <a href="https://yachtcharterbook.com/ru/yacht-charter/country/230/area/282/prop_type/6">Парусные катамараны (1)</a>
                    </div>
                </div><div class="objects">
                    <div class="link">
                        <a href="https://yachtcharterbook.com/ru/yacht-charter/country/230/area/282/prop_type/5">Парусные яхты (13)</a>
                    </div>
                </div><div class="objects">
                    <div class="link">
                        <a href="https://yachtcharterbook.com/ru/yacht-charter/country/230/area/282">Все яхты (14)</a>
                    </div>
                </div></div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Solved. Just added optimized: false to marker.

```
latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(38.909593, -76.419036);
                marker[282] = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLng,
                map: map,
                icon: defIcon,
                optimized: false
            });
```